# Not able to show a toast message or open new activity on cardview item ClickListener in gridlayout...!

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

Here is my java show.
I am not able to open new activity or show a toast message on cardview item OnClickListener. I use **gridlayout** as the id of main Grid Layout in XML

```
package com.example.shakeelmughal.assanislam;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout gridLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);

        setSingleClick(gridLayout);
    }

    private void setSingleClick(GridLayout gridLayout) {
        for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            CardView cardView = (CardView)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            final int s=1;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Item "+ s +"Cicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

XML code. Main GridLayout and in it i use cardview.Every card have a ImageView & a TextView. I use 5 rows and 10 cols in it. activity_home.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shakeelmughal.assanislam.HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bk"
        android:weightSum="16">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textGrid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/test"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
            android:layout_weight="14"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="6"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="14dp">

            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/tahart"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tahart"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/namaz"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Namaz"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Row 2 -->
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/hajj2"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hajj"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/roza"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Roza"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Row 3 -->
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/dua"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Dua"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/zakat"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Zakat"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Row 4 -->
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/compass"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Compass"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/roza"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Roza"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Row 4 -->
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/dua"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Dua"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/zakat"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Zakat"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- Row 5 -->
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/compass"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Compass"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/roza"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Roza"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to show"? Does the app crash or it ignores the click? Please also include the `activity_home.xml` file. Thanks

Comment: I want to show new activity on click

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your layout has been inflated yet in onCreate, so children views do not yet exist. Try moving your setSingleClick() to onCreateView.